# QGIS - Import transposed points coordinates/nodes as polygons

Tags: qgis, csv, json

I'm attempting to streamline the process of importing polygons (19 in this case) from a website into QGIS. I extracted the JSON using chrome's dev tools and converted it into CSV spreadsheet [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2kx92wb391dtyn/RPA%20Parcels.csv?dl=0). The screenshot below taken from the csv file is structured in such a way that each feature is contained to a single row. Nodes are listed in columns with eastings followed by northings. Critically, there is an ordering to the nodes as indicated by the column headers. Eastings and northings are denoted with a 0 and 1 at the end respectively. The centre number increments up by one with each pair of eastings/northings.

Is there a way to input the data into QGIS with python that will plot each node in the correct order and then use points to path followed with lines to polygons? 
The end result should look like the screenshot taken from the website below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try saving the json in a file, then drag-drop in QGIS. You might not need the conversion you are describing

Comment: That's so clever, I just love QGIS...thanks!

Comment: ok, turning the comment into an answer for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to save your data in a json file, and to drag & drop this file in QGIS.

The conversion you are describing would not be needed then.